# Disputed when it's actually closed

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I'm confused as to why on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57428166/how-to-have-a-hover-effect-on-inputtype-button-and-how-to-fix-the-cursor-probl) my flag got disputed:

> [image: disputed flag]

When the close reason was [the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3sid.png):

> [image]

Comment: People incorrectly thought the question looked ok in [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23753823) and disputed your flag

Comment: Uh.. I'm not sure what does review should be doing. But that specific question has several issue such as mispell, superflous content yet it was deemed as "Looks Ok" :)

Comment: @Shinjo "Looks OK" is very deceptive in what it means. And I absolutely hate it - it's been brought up a lot, too. Basically, it means "It's suitable as a question", as in "it doesn't need closing". It's the opposite to casting a close vote. It doesn't necessarily mean the question is *answerable* - it might not be but the reviewers are not necessarily versed in the language/tech in it, so their judgement might be a bit off. Unfortunately, there is a sizeable portion of reviewers that just hit "Looks OK" for anything to just finish reviews as fast as possible. You might have been their victim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57428166/timeline) for the question, you'll notice that it went through Triage and was voted Looks OK. This is when your flag became disputed. Later, it was manually closed by three different users after the typo was pointed out, but this doesn't change the state of any already resolved flags.

Comment: Does the timeline for every single question or post refer to the same URL? `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/timeline`?

Comment: @Shinjo Correct. You can also use [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/obsolete-add-timeline-and-revisions-links) to add a link to the timeline on every post.